# How can I parse com.abc.def.abcdef-1.6.0_newversion-2.3.7-debug in presto

Tags: regex, presto

I am new to regular expressions and need some help. I am using Presto and need to parse '1.6.0' from
'com.abc.def.abcdef-1.6.0_newversion-2.3.7-debug'? Any ideas how can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `[\d.]+(?=_)` or even `[\d.]++(?=_)`

Comment: Maybe `[\d\.]+(?=_)`

Comment: find "_" and read backward until "-" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
[0-9.]+(?=_)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aY0vS1/1)

The `[0-9.]+(?=_)` pattern matches 1 or more digits or literal dots before a `_`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much. I also found this site: https://regex101.com/ for all beginners who want to dive deeper into regex.

Comment: That's precisely the site you linked to :)  Thanks again!

Comment: Note that regex101.com is good for PCRE/JS/Python regex testing. .NET, Java and others can be tested only to some extent, and only when you know what you are doing :)

Comment: Use `[\d.]+_[^-]+`

Comment: Thanks! (i had asked how would I parse '1.6.0_newversion' if I needed to but deleted the question before I thought I got a response)